# PHP readfile() on large files (over 2GB) ending prematurely

Tags: php, iis

I have a download script that downloads large files, (usually over 2gb, sometimes over 10gb). The downloads seems to fail at random times.

note: I am using iis

```
 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    $filename = 'https://downloadurl.com/SAS9_4W64.zip';
    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers("https://downloadurl.com/SAS9.3TS132bit.zip", TRUE));

    $extension = fileexten($filename);
    $fakename = 'SAS9.3TS132bitz';
    if(($filename!= false)&&($fakename!=false&& @fopen('https://downloadurl.com/SAS9.3TS132bit.zip','r')==true)){
    $mime = contenttype($extension);
    set_time_limit(0);

header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header("Content-Type:".$mime);
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);        


    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fakename.'.'.$extension);

    header('Expires: 0'); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
ob_clean();
ob_end_clean();
@readfile($filename);
session_write_close();
    }
```

Comment: 32-bit PHP or 64-bit PHP? The filepointer used to maintain the current position in the file is a 32-bit signed integer in 32-bit PHP, giving problems with files larger than 2GB

Comment: I installed 64-bit PHP and ended up with the same issue.